# Export firing before the function return, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have this function get the token from api and check if I have admin permission. The problem is my export its firing before of the checking of the function.

```
const async = [
  { path: '*', redirect: '/404', hidden: true }
]
     
    var hasAdmin = getAdmin()
        if (hasAdmin === undefined || hasAdmin === null) {
          var token = null
          var url = null
          var uri = window.location.href.split('?')
          if (uri.length === 2) {
            var vars = uri[1].split('&')
            var getVars = {}
            var tmp = ''
            vars.forEach(function(v) {
              tmp = v.split('=')
              if (tmp.length === 2) {
                getVars[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
              }
              token = getVars.AUTH_ID
              url = getVars.DOMAIN
            })
            getUserAdmin(url, token)
              .then(response => {
                var hasAdmin = response.result
                if (hasAdmin === true) {
                console.log('hasAdmin: ' + hasAdmin)
                  async.push(adminRouter)
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
              })
          }
        } else if (hasAdmin === true) {
          async.push(adminRouter)
        }
    
    export const asyncRoutes = async
    console.log('hasAdmin2: ' + hasAdmin)
```

Here is how Im using the const asyncRoutes:

```
import { asyncRoutes, constantRoutes } from '@/router'

/**
 * Use meta.role to determine if the current user has permission
 * @param roles
 * @param route
 */
function hasPermission(roles, route) {
  if (route.meta && route.meta.roles) {
    return roles.some(role => route.meta.roles.includes(role))
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

/**
 * Filter asynchronous routing tables by recursion
 * @param routes asyncRoutes
 * @param roles
 */
export function filterAsyncRoutes(routes, roles) {
  const res = []

  routes.forEach(route => {
    const tmp = { ...route }
    if (hasPermission(roles, tmp)) {
      if (tmp.children) {
        tmp.children = filterAsyncRoutes(tmp.children, roles)
      }
      res.push(tmp)
    }
  })

  return res
}

const state = {
  routes: [],
  addRoutes: []
}

const mutations = {
  SET_ROUTES: (state, routes) => {
    state.addRoutes = routes
    state.routes = constantRoutes.concat(routes)
  }
}
const actions = {
  generateRoutes({ commit }, roles) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let accessedRoutes
      if (roles.includes('admin')) {
        accessedRoutes = asyncRoutes || []
      } else {
        accessedRoutes = filterAsyncRoutes(asyncRoutes, roles)
      }
      commit('SET_ROUTES', accessedRoutes)
      resolve(accessedRoutes)
    })
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

I always need reload(f5) the page in first access to gets the menu admin.

Await from promise dont works because de export should be always in the top. Some idea how can I fix this?

obs: attention in variable hasAdmin

[image]

Comment: since `getUserAdmin` is asynchronous- of course the console.logs in the .then will occur after the console.log at the end of the code - that's how asynchrony works

Comment: I make some changes in the code and image. I think its more easy to understand now

Comment: The menu admin never come in firts access. I need reload(f5) the page to get the menu

Comment: can you show how you import this module - you'll probably need to change how you use this module, because as it is, it's doing exactly as expected

Comment: Yeah, I will add in question

Comment: So you said promises wont work because of order. HAHA export a promise XD This might screw you over with the code you wrote for using `asyncConst` but it can be done.

Comment: forgot this: You can then `await asyncRoutes` or call `.then`
since it kind of answers your question but not directly I abstained from posting it as an answer but I could if you want

Comment: Can you posting lik a answer? I think this can be works